# Ajax post after get(Partial view)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a fully ajax oriented admin panel. In a section that i got a partial view by using ajax, i want to post that form after i get it.

I get my partial view with this code:

```
    function AddNewsGet() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Get/GetANG/',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        $('#divMain').html(result);
    })
};
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult GetANG()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/AdminPartials/_Addnews.cshtml");
    }
```

Getting it works like a charm but i can't post it. Tried this, didn't work.

```
function AddNewsPost() {
        var nws = {
            nHeader: $('#txtHeader').val(),
            nContent: $('#txtContent').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddNews", "Admin")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: nws,
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Saved !');
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm aware of the fact that ajax doesn't actually writes html code into the document so thats probably why i can't use my post function.

How can i fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post the code for the partial view and the method you post back to.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get the javascript code from my admin layout and didn't work. I moved the ajax post function to my partial view and it worked. Thanks you.